# Impersonal Verbs: Are Active Transitives Possible?

Tags: verbs, syntax, voice, impersonal

Latin utilizes some verbs that pretty much only occur impersonally, like *oportet*.  One can also regularly form impersonal actives from intransitive verbs like *placeo* and impersonal passives from transitive verbs like *dico*.

Is it possible to form impersonal actives of transitive verbs?

This doesn't seem to be a necessity as if the patient is not impersonal, one can use the personal passive, and if the patient and agent are both impersonal, one can use the impersonal passive.  However, this isn't quite the case as there are defective transitive verbs like *aio*.  So maybe a specific subquestion would be whether *ait* is ever used impersonally.

Comment: What would an impersonal _ait_ mean? Something like "they say" or "people say"?

Comment: @Draconis I suppose.  I guess I am wondering for a defective verb that lacks a passive whether *ait* as impersonal would mean what *aitur* would mean if it existed.  What I am wondering in general is different.  In English you can have impersonal transitive actives: "How's it going?"  "It sucks %^&*s".  Can you do that in Latin, or do you have to say "%^&*s are being sucked"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a couple of examples from Plautus that could be relevant for your question:

a. Personal use of a transitive verb like *decet*:

> *contempla ut haec (vestis) me deceat* (Pl. *Most.* 172). 'See how this dress suits me.'

b. [Impersonal use of a transitive verb like *decet*](https://books.google.es/books?id=5Oh2oGRUpgUC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=%22impersonal%20verbs%20that%20combine%20with%20an%20accusative%22&source=bl&ots=zEE3K73a7a&sig=ACfU3U080-AbZews_WXVnM5wLWUf22kgqQ&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiszJ_c5-PqAhVsA2MBHWTEAT4Q6AEwAXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22impersonal%20verbs%20that%20combine%20with%20an%20accusative%22&f=false):

> *ita ut vos decet* (Pl. *Most.* 729). 'so as befits you'.

The following example could also be useful for you. Note that in this example *fallit* is a transitive verb that is also used impersonally:

> *nisi me fallit* (Cic. *Fam.* 5, 20, 6), 'unless I am mistaken' ('unless it deceives me').

See [A&G (1903: 388c: pp. 241-242)](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/accusative-direct-object) for other similar impersonal verbs that take accusative case.

From a more theoretical point of view, those impersonal verbs that take accusative case are expected to be grammatically marked (e.g., compared to the ones that take dative: cf. *ita nobis decet* (Ter. *Ad.* 928), 'thus it befits us'). Cf. the so-called ["Burzio's Generalization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burzio%27s_generalization), whereby, if a verb does not assign a semantic function to its subject, then it does not assign accusative case to its object.

Note also that Burzio's famous grammatical generalization appears to be infringed by the well-known constructions of the [*pudet me tui*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/what-is-the-grammatical-logic-of-impersonal-constructions-like-me-non-solum-p) type since these verbs assign accusative case to the experiencer object but do not assign any semantic function to their subject (these verbs are impersonal). Interestingly, the accusative case of the experiencer argument of these stative psychological verbs has been originally related to those causative verbs of the 2nd conjugation. Cf. [Matasović's (2013)](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/indo/118/2013/article-p93.xml?language=de)  proposal that "the irregular case-frames of the Latin bivalent statives are innovations based on the analogy with the case-frames of causative verbs, which had the Causee argument in the accusative case".

Note how this proposal somewhat restores Burzio's insight. The impersonal verbs at issue here assign accusative case to their experiencer object since they can be originally related to (not impersonal!) transitive verbs with causative meaning. As predicted by Burzio, those transitive verbs that assign accusative case are **not** (initially!) expected to be impersonal.

So, as for your question above ("Is it possible to form impersonal actives of transitive verbs?"), my preliminary answer is: yes, but only secondarily (e.g., through an analogical process. Cf. Matasović's (2013) proposal). NB: not primarily, because of Burzio's Generalization.

Comment: This is indeed most of what I am looking for.  I'd also be interested if there are examples that don't feel like they *ought* to take the dative...e.g., examples of straightforward action verbs like "strikes" or "sucks" or "kills" appearing as active impersonals.

Comment: @CMonsour The English verbs you mention are **causative** verbs that can be interpreted psychologically. Note that Lat. stative verbs of the _pudet_ type are also psychological and their accusative case has been originally related to those causative verbs of the 2nd conjugation. Cf. Matasović's  (2013) proposal that "the irregular case-frames of the Latin bivalent statives are innovations based on the analogy with the case-frames of causative verbs, which had the Causee argument in the accusative case". https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/indo/118/2013/article-p93.xml?language=de

Comment: Thanks for copying that material into your answer!

Comment: However, while I can see how "it kills me" uses "kills" as a psychological verb, I don't see how you can make the same claim about how "it sucks balls" uses "sucks".

Comment: @CMonsour Your example _it kills me_ involves figurative usage but contains a "normal" transitive verb, i.e., a transitive verb whose subject (the pronoun _it_) is semantically interpreted as a Cause argument. So this example, unlike the Latin ones discussed above (e.g. the _pudet_-type ones), lacks impersonality. Same with the idiomatic expression _It sucks balls_: I understand this _it_ is referring to something (e.g. a movie). So I'd not consider it impersonal either. Note also that _Hoc/id_ (nominative) VERB _me_ (accusative) is not (usually considered) an impersonal construction in Latin.

Comment: OK, I probably should have been more clear.  While "It sucks balls" is usually not an impersonal construction, it certainly is in response to the question "How's it going?"

Comment: @CMonsour Ok, I see. So it seems that "it sucks balls" is a kind of idiomatic expression where the subject pronoun "it" (unlike the one of "_it_ kills me", right?) can be a sort of expletive (i.e., non-meaningful) pronoun similar to the one of the impersonal construction "_it_ rains cats and dogs". As I pointed out before in a previous post, it would be nice if we could have a database on idiomatic expressions of Latin: cf.  https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11270/is-there-any-database-on-idiomatic-expressions-in-latin

Comment: Aren't meteorological expressions like "it rains" classic examples of impersonals?

Comment: @CMonsour That's right! Impersonal constructions like _It rains_ have an expletive (i.e., non-meaningful) subject in English. Note instead that the subject of _it kills me_ is meaningful since the pronoun _it_ is the Cause of _killing_. Thanks for letting me know that _it sucks balls_ can also be used as an impersonal construction (NB: I'm not a native speaker of English).

Comment: @Mitomino: Having proven the case with "nisi me fallit", why express doubt at the end? In the cited pages from (A & G): p.388(a): "Many verbs apparently intransitive, expressing feeling, take an accusative, and may be used in the passive." Three examples are given, the third of which: "ridetur ab omni conventu" = "he is laughed at by the whole assembly"; where is the accusative, here? This is faintly reminiscent of "nisi mihi irisisset" from Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12992/1982, in which a directional prefix, "ir" (= "in") applied to verb "rideo", demands a dative (mihi)

Comment: @Mitomino: indirect object. The logic is clear: the ridicule is directed at someone--directional, by definition. Why is "mihi" labelled "indirect" when it is substituting for what would normally be the accusative direct-object, "me", e.g. "me ridet" = "he is laughing at me" (A & G)?

Comment: @tony note that your interesting example _ridetur ab omni conventu_ is **ambiguous** since it can be interpreted as a personal passive of a transitive use, i.e., with an elliptical personal subject (your interpretation: "**he** is laughed at by the whole assembly") but also as an **impersonal** passive of its intransitive use (i.e., 'laughing is being done by the whole assembly'). Note the very important point that impersonal passives in Latin can *also* take agentive _by_-phrases.

Comment: E.g., cf. Caesar's (_BG_ 2.33.3) example _Pugnatum ab hostibus acriter est_. CF. https://books.google.es/books?id=yxxfCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA164-IA39&lpg=PA164-IA39&dq=Pugnatum+ab+hostibus+acriter+est&source=bl&ots=aieV8oDoX-&sig=ACfU3U1m5apUFhiEkcSHDktnAZqs88MxaQ&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS1NDMte7qAhUP4YUKHaDcDCg4ChDoATAEegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=Pugnatum%20ab%20hostibus%20acriter%20est&f=false

Comment: @Mitomino: Thank you. The "nisi mihi irisisset" vs "nisi me risisset" conflict: thinking and paraphrasing: "If he (the subject) had not directed (verb) the ridicule (direct object) at/to me (indirect object [mihi])". The difference is now clear between the  directionally-prefixed verb, "irrideo", demanding a dative indirect-object; and, the non-prefixed parent verb, "rideo", which demands an accusative direct-object, "me". It pays, at least initially, to translate literally.